# vue.js how to show progress if processing data

Tags: vuejs2

I have a page build in vue.js where an API is called (using axios) getting a large json object (1k+).

While I am processing this object, I want to show user the progress of the operation - nothing fancy like progress bars, just a simple "Processed X from Y".

I have found example on how to do this in jquery of pure JS, but I can get this to work in vue.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my skeleton code:

```
    <div>Processed {{processed.current}} of {{processed.total}} records</div>

    <script>
    data() {
        return {
          progress:{
            current:0,
            total: 0
          },
          records: [],
        };
      },
      mounted() {
        this.getRecords();
      },
      methods: {
        getRecords(){
          axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: process.env.VUE_APP_REPORTING_API + "/Reports/orders",
            headers: {
              "content-type": "application/json",
              Authorization: this.$cookie.get("wwa_token")
            }
          }).then(
                  result => {
                    this.progress.total = result.data.length;

                   //and here where the loop should happen, something like this
                   //obviously the below won't work :)
                   result.data.forEach(function(item) {
                        this.records.push(item);
                        this.progress.current++;
                      }
                  },
                  error => {
                  }
          );
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: what kind of error do you get while running your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious problem with the posted code is that it has a syntax error (missing a closing parenthesis) and it establishes a new context. The code would (sort of) "work" if it was changed it to use arrow functions:

```
result.data.forEach(item => {
    this.records.push(item);
    this.progress.current++;
});
```

However, I don't think that's going to do what you want. The JavaScript code will process all the items before the user interface updates, so all the user would see would be "Processed N of N records". Even if you inserted a `this.$forceUpdate()` in the loop to make the interface update at each iteration, the changes would still be too fast for any user to see.

The real problem is that "processing" all the items only takes a few milliseconds. So it's always going to happen too quickly to show intermediate results.

If you're trying to show the progress of the AJAX request/response, that's an entirely different question which will require coordination between the client and the server. Search for HTTP chunked responses for a start.

Comment: the missing parenthesis was a mistake from cleaning the code for SO. The processing can take quite a few seconds as the vue tries to populate a table with sometime close to 2k row, sometime more :/